# how to show selected text in combobox using custom template

Tags: wpf, combobox, controltemplate

I'm new in WPF, implementing application to show 2 combobox with different formated text.

I have created custom controltemplate for combobox

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridGenreComboboxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <ToggleButton  
                                  IsTabStop="False" x:Name="DropDownToggle"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}" 
                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" 
                                  Margin="10,4" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"/>

                            </Style>
                        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text ="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>

                </ToggleButton>


                <!-- Popup for dropdown when combobox is clicked and open -->
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True"
                           Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                           PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                    <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border x:Name="Splitter" BorderThickness="0,3,0,0">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                                        <Color R="58" G="64" B="70" A="255"/>
                                    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                                </SolidColorBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>

                        <Grid Margin="0,3,0,0">
                            <Border CornerRadius="0,0,2,2" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="Green">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.9">
                                        <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                                            <Color R="96" G="96" B="97" A="255"/>
                                        </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                                    </SolidColorBrush>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                            </Border>

                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" x:Name="Content"
                                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

in one combobox want to show formated text i.e. 1000 x 900, 200 x 300,.. and in another want to show
text like 1000 900 topology, 200 300 topology

I have formated combobox item and it shows correct value but selected value doesn't show on combobox.
how to do this using single combobox item template?

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"   ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleTopologysNew}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTopologyNew}"             
                      Template="{StaticResource GridGenreComboboxTemplate}"  
                      >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} x {1}">
                                    <Binding Path="LeftNumber"/>
                                    <Binding Path="RightNumber"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>

                    </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>

 <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"   ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleTopologysNew}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTopologyNew}"             
                      Template="{StaticResource GridGenreComboboxTemplate}"  
                      >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}  {1} topology">
                                    <Binding Path="LeftNumber"/>
                                    <Binding Path="RightNumber"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>

                    </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fix is simple... just *don't* declare a new `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox` - use the default one. If you *really* need to provide your own `ControlTemplate`, then just define one that contains the `TextBox` used to display the selected value. If you are new to WPF, then I very much doubt that you actually need to define your own `ControlTemplate`.

If however, you *do* need to declare your own `ControlTemplate`, then you should start with the default one (which you can find in the [ComboBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN) and slowly and carefully remove the bits that you don't need and add the new bits that you do need. However, when declaring a `ControlTemplate`, you have to replace like with like. For example, look at the `ContentPresenter` from the default `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
    IsHitTestVisible="False"
    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
    Margin="3,3,23,3"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

Now look at yours:

```
<ContentPresenter 
    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}" 
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" 
    Margin="10,4" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

To start with, you are attempting to data bind the `ContentPresenter.Content` property to a different property from the original `ControlTemplate`. So if I were you, I'd get rid of you non-working `ControlTemplate` and replace it with the original one. Ensure that it displays correctly before starting to change it and test it regularly as you continue to change it.

Comment: Default combobox is working. But want to use custom control. only. I tried what you have updated but its not working, can you please check at you end

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that your solution was to just replace that one example that I pointed out to you. I was saying that when you want to create your own `ControlTemplate`, you should start with the default one and make your changes slowly and carefully and to test it regularly during this process. So you said the default one is working. Now you just have to alter it bit by bit until it fulfils your requirements.

Comment: by adding ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" resolve this issue.                     Thanks a lot, i was trying to resolve this issue from last 4 days and you solved it within half and hour. really appreciated your help.

Comment: I have another query, above template is common in our project which doesn't have ContentTemplate set. but for my combobox i need to set ContentTemplate, 
in this case, do i need to copy same custom control code for my combobox and add contentTemplate or is there any way to use same control template code and set content template in my combobox code.?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. `ContentTemplate` is a property of the `ContentControl` and/or `ContentPresenter` classes. What do they have to do with your `ComboBox`? Either way, if you are asking how to apply this `ContentTemplate` to your other controls, then you can just declare it in `Application.Resources` *without an `x:Key` value*. See the 'The DataType Property' section of the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information on this.

Comment: Also, if this answer has helped you to solve your problem, then please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as is customary on this website.